# Odoo 8 - Domain filter

Tags: odoo-8

I'm using the domain to filter a many2one field on another field.

Example:
I have a product field and want to filter my serial number field on product (to display only the serial numbers of the selected product type).

So my code is:

```
<field name="product_id"/>
<field name="product_lot" domain="[('product_id', 'in', [product_id])]"/>
```

This code's working, but when no product is selected, i'd like to display all the serial numbers available. But with my code, there's no serial number in my list.

I am unable to find the syntax to test if no product is selected, i display all the serial number, else, i display only the serial numbers matching the selected product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with python code :

```
def on_change_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, context=None):
    if product_id:
        result = {
            'domain': {
                'product_lot': [('product_id', 'in', [product_id])],
            },
        }
    else:
        result = {
            'domain': {
                'product_lot': '',
            },
        }

    return result
```

It works, but i thought it was possible to do the same simply in the XML...